# Determination of the main colors of the image by percentage

Tags: javascript, image, opencv, colors, cluster-analysis

I have identified 8 colors: 3 from the RGB model, 4 from the CMYK model (cyan, pink, yellow and black) and white.
From the image, I need to determine what percentage of each color is contained in the image

```
const colors = [
     {r: 255, g: 0, b: 0, name: 'red'},
     {r: 0, g: 255, b: 0, name: 'green'},
     {r: 0, g: 0, b: 255, name: 'blue'},
     {r: 0, g: 255, b: 255, name: 'cyan'},
     {r: 255, g: 0, b: 255, name: 'pink'},
     {r: 255, g: 255, b: 0, name: 'yellow'},
     {r: 0, g: 0, b: 0, name: 'black'},
     {r: 255, g: 255, b: 255, name: 'white'}
]
```

The number of colors is determined by finding the minimum discrepancy between the color of a pixel in the picture and one of the above colors:

```
const colorNumber = (color, pixel_rgba) => {
    const number = Math.abs(color.r - pixel_rgba.r) + Math.abs(color.g - pixel_rgba.g) + Math.abs(color.b - pixel_rgba.b)
    return number
}
```

The program works fine with simple images (documents or clearly distinguishable colors), but detects too much black and white on "complex" images

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfhqU.jpg)

I understand why this is happening, but I would like to avoid it and make the definition of primary colors more "human"

Please advise the algorithm for determining the nearest color, which allows you to get rid of excess white and black

Editted:
I tried artificially increasing the color difference if it is white or black, but it seems to me that this method cannot be called good:

```
const colorNumber = (color, pixel_rgba) => {
    const number = Math.abs(color.r - pixel_rgba.r) + Math.abs(color.g - pixel_rgba.g) + Math.abs(color.b - pixel_rgba.b)
    return color.name === "black" || color.name === "white" ? number * 2 : number
}
```

Comment: If you `understand why this is happening`, could you please share your understanding?

Comment: @Kosh
For example, the light green color is closer to white (from the point of view of the algorithm) than to green, but we perceive it more as green and not as white

Comment: Talking about perception means talking about ranges. I'd suggest to represent colors as ranges, then check if pixel color belongs to those ranges.

Comment: @Kosh
Thanks for the idea. I need to make the black and white ranges smaller than the others